# Invented logic switch to supply power to DC/DC

Tags: mosfet, bjt, dc-dc-converter, control

I have a controller where by the GPIO's pins when ACTIVATED is pulled low.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJs1GA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I want to use transistors and FETs in such a way that when the GPIO is activated (Pulled low) it will supply power to two DC/DC converters.

The first DC/DC input is 60V and the output is 12V DC at 2A. [Datasheet](https://mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/VRB_LD-30WR2.pdf)

The second DC/DC input is also 80V and the output is 5V DC at 4A. [Datashhet](https://mantech.co.za/Datasheets/Products/VRA_LD-30WR2.pdf)

IS my circuit correct? Am I missing something that I am not seeing?

Secondly, I feel (could be wrong) there is a better and less complex way to achieve this sort of logic.

So when the GPIO is pulled low, the switch turns on and supplies power to the DC/DC.

Here is my circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsh7Wx.png)</sup>

Edit 2:

[image]

Comment: With that circuit 8 A will flow through R7 when M1 turns on. You will dissipate \$ P = I^2R = 8^2 \times 10 = 640\ \text W\$ in R7. Not good. Add in the datasheet links for the DC/DC converters and we'll see if there's a better way.

Comment: @Transistor I have added the 12V DC/DC and 5V DC/DC. Input the was supposed to be 60V DC not 80V, incorrectly typed that.

Comment: The second unit has a Ctrl input which allows remote shutdown. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: You need to put the switching transistor in place of R7, and delete M1 - as it is now, M1 makes a short circuit across the inputs to the regulators, and wastes some 360 watts.

Comment: @PeterBennett gees only seeing that now as well, I was only concentrating on the BJT to get the logic of the circuit correct, didn't even realize the short.

Comment: @PeterBennett what do you mean by putting a switching transistor in place of R7? Do you mean add anoter NPN or repurpose Q1 or Q2?

Comment: If you want to switch power to the 12V and 5v regulators, your switching device, whatever it is, must replace your R7, and it must be able to hanlde the current required by the 12V and 5V regulators.  2N3904 and 2N3906 definitely won't handle the current.

Comment: @Transistor just checking if you see/saw a better way?

Comment: Do you understand how the Ctrl input works? You can drive that directly from your control circuit.

Comment: @Transistor I do know how to use the ctrl. Basically 0V to Crtl means ouput is off and >3V is ON. Not sure how to adapt my circuit. And what if for instance this DC/DC is no longer sold and the replacement DC/DC does not have a Crtl, just Vin, Vout and GND.

Comment: Find an alternative supplier that does have the control circuit. It saves a load of messing, external components and heat.

Comment: @Transistor can you check my edit 2 in the post, from the sims I only need a single NPN now. Vout goes to the RC of the DC/DC, D1 is a 12V zener.

Comment: Do you mean *inverted* where you say invented?

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTPRTg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. For the DC/DC converter with the Ctrl input a simple inverter is all that's required. If the Ctrl input has a pull-up then R2 may be omitted.*

I see that you're using 2.8 V logic so you need to check if the Ctrl input will work at such a low 'logic high' voltage.

Comment: The worst case cntrl value is 3V to switch on. Also I realized this will not work because if the control circuit is damaged or not properly connected( I should have mentioned I insert a cable into the gpio and screw it down) then the NPN is off which mean the dc/dc is till on at the output which I do not want for safety. The output should only be on when the control circuit is properly connected.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is with a spst Normally open relay where the coil goes to 12V using a zener and the other end of the coil goes to the gpio and the 12V signal goes on Com and ctrl goes on Normally open pin of the relay

Comment: I need to add a second external pull-up to the base of the BJT. So in the event the internal control circuitry is not working as expected the external circuit (my circuit) will make the DC/DC turn off.